# OpenVPN - client sees the server AND the LAN, but not the Internet

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have the following OpenVPN setup:

```
Client(android OpenVPN client) <-> internet <-> VPN server (linux) <-> LAN
```

VPN server has **eth0** (visible on the open internet) and **eth1** (part of the local, firewalled LAN, 192.168.1.0/24). I used the "NAT hack" to make computers in the local LAN visible to the client, using the following:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

since I don't have access to the DHCP server which pushes IP configuration to majority of the computers in the LAN.

Now I have the following situation:

- Client connects to server without problems
- Configuration gets pushed to the client
- I can see the computers in the local LAN (this seems to be the difference with solutions I could find - all other questions dealt with the absence of the "NAT hack" - I have that sorted out!)
- But I **don't have access to the internet**

The configuration that is pushed from the server to the client is:

```
'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway autolocal bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,redirect-gateway defl,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5' (status=1)
```

As you can see, valid (google) DNS is provided, so that cannot be an issue, AFAIK. "redirect-gateway autolocal" should take care of the internet access, but it doesn't. "redirect-gateway dfl" does not change anything.

I am pretty sure I am missing either additional iptable line or a route... but I am lost as what it should be.

To clarify: I am looking for a way to access the internet via VPN, not for the traffic to pass VPN! And, I am unable to ping 8.8.8.8 from the client, so the DNS is not the issue.

Edit: Yes, I enabled IPV4 forwarding. I assume that local LAN would not be visible without it.

```
pi@router:~ $ sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.ip_forward    
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: Have you enabled forwarding? Please show output for `sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.ip_forward`.

Comment: I did (I edited the post to reflect this). As explained, I have no problem seeing the local LAN, so **most** of the settings should be ok (unlike basically every one newbie post about OpenVPN having no access to the net - either they did not enable forwarding or NAT). That's why I am puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I'm understand your problem. You configure NAT only for access to LAN, to make access to WAN you should add another rule `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`.

**Update:** Easiest way to check that you're not flooding WAN with private IPs, to check output on eth0 using tcpdump, for example `tcpdump -n -i eth0 | grep 192.168.0`. If there is no packets, so everything is Ok.

Comment: Nope. Does not improve anything. But I think you have a point here. I have no rule to route openvpn traffic to public net, but this line will not address that (it routes the LAN to the net, but not the vpn).

Comment: @xmp125a in that case you will have double NAT, once it NAT from VPN network to LAN and second one NAT from LAN to WAN network. Did you have access from LAN to WAN?

Comment: I had that access before through different router on a LAN network. Now I finally got it right 

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

did the trick.But now I am not sure whether I am not flooding the outside net with 192.168.1.0\24 packets... will have to check this.

Comment: @xmp125a you not flooding outside net with 192.168.1.0/24 packets. It's NATed.

Comment: Can you fix your answer so I can greencheck it?

Comment: @xmp125a updated,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61477/discussion-between-alexander-t-and-xmp125a).